# How do you implement payments in React Native 0.70?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, stripe-payments, payment

How do you implement payments in React Native 0.70. I worked with earlier React Native versions using react-native-credit-card-input and react-native-credit-card-input-plus that are now breaking.

Comment: Stripe is a good option https://stripe.com/docs/libraries/react-native

Comment: @Ansh stripe.com/docs/libraries/react-native is not working either.

Comment: If someone is still looking at this question, i found a great fix here https://github.com/sbycrosz/react-native-credit-card-input/issues/229

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now it very easy to implement the payment methods in react-native because stripe provide official [doc](https://stripe.com/docs/libraries/react-native).

They provide a built-in UI for checkout and **Card Tokenisation**,
[Here you can Follow Official Doc](https://stripe.com/docs/libraries/react-native)

**1) Setup**

install stripe official react-native sdk

```
yarn add @stripe/stripe-react-native
```

To initialise Stripe in your React Native app, either wrap your payment screen with the StripeProvider component, or use the initStripe initialisation method.

```
<StripeProvider publishableKey={PUBLISHABLE_KEY}>
    <Navigation />
 </StripeProvider>
```

[How to get PUBLISHABLE_KEY](https://stripe.com/docs/keys#obtain-api-keys)

Now in your component

Either use the Stripe UI or create your own custom UI for getting card details. In this answer, I'm using [rn-credit-card](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-credit-card) for getting a card, which gives me customization options .

**2) Get Card details, create Card Token and save for future use**

```
import CreditCardForm, { FormModel } from "rn-credit-card";

const handleConfirm = (model: FormModel) => {
   axios
  .post(
    "https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens",
    {
      "card[name]": model.holderName,
      "card[number]": model.cardNumber,
      "card[exp_month]": model.expiration.split("/")[0],
      "card[exp_year]": model.expiration.split("/")[1],
      "card[cvc]": model.cvv,
    },
    {
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${STRIPE_KEY}`,
      },
    }
  )
  .then((res) => {
    if (res?.data?.id) {
        //res?.data?.id It will return the payment method ID sent to your backend
        // You can also save it for future use by saving it in the database.
      console.log(res?.data?.id)
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    Alert.alert("Stripe Error", err.message);
  });
```

};

For setting defaultValues

```
const formMethods = useForm<FormModel>({
mode: "onBlur",
defaultValues: {
  holderName: "",
  cardNumber: "",
  expiration: "",
  cvv: "",
},
 });
const { handleSubmit, formState } = formMethods;
```

Form to get card details

```
<CreditCardForm
        LottieView={LottieView}
        horizontalStart={false}
        overrides={{
          labelText: {
            marginTop: 16,
          },
        }}
      />
    {formState.isValid && (
      <Button
        style={styles.button}
        title={'CONFIRM PAYMENT'}
        onPress={handleSubmit(handleConfirm)}
      />
    )}
```

Now When you pay or checkout simple do the following step

**3) Checkout or Payment Time**

1. Create a PaymentIntent by passing the paymentMethods Id with other params like reservationId etc
2. The backend will return you clientSecret and also the calculated bill
3. Send the clientSecret to stripe

```
import { useStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-react-native";

  const { confirmPayment } = useStripe();
const handlePay = async () => {
setStripeLoading(true);
try {
//Step 1
  const response = await createPaymentIntent({
    variables: {
      paymentMethodId: paymentMethodId, // That you stored on the backend
      reserveId: id, // In our case reserveId is required 
      amountToDeduct: 23,
    },
  });
  if (response) {
      //Step 2 by getting clientSecret
    const { clientSecret } = response?.createPaymentIntent;
//sending clientSecret to deduct amount
    const { error, paymentIntent } = await confirmPayment(clientSecret);
    if (error) {
      setStripeLoading(false);
      Alert.alert(`Error code: ${error.code}`, error.message);
    }
    if (paymentIntent) {
      setStripeLoading(false);
      // Show Success Alert
    }
  }
} catch (error) {
  setStripeLoading(false);
} finally {
  setStripeLoading(false);
}
};
```

Tada you done